# If I added a Capacitor to this circuit would it charge both and would the charge led still work?

Tags: led, capacitor, charger, capacitance, electrolytic-capacitor

[image]

If I were to add a second capacitor to this circuit of roughly the same capacitance (120uf). Would this circuit charge both up completely, and would the LED still accurately depict if the combined two capacitors are charged. Does adding another capacitor not work or cause the circuit to not work?

Comment: "*If I were to add a second capacitor to this circuit of roughly the same capacitance (120uf)*". Where would you put it?

Comment: In line with the other one to make it like one bigger capacitor.

Comment: You have confused "in line" with "across".

Answer (score 0):

A second identical capacitor in parallel with the first would double the energy available to the flash,  resulting in brighter flashes, longer charge-up time and fewer flashes before the tube fails.

It's not an LED it's a neon, but yeah it responds to the voltage in the capacitors, so it will still indicate that the circuit is ready to fire.

Comment: it seems to take less time for the light/led/neon to become a solid red color meaning it's ready. Shouldn't it take longer if anything, that is what i don't understand.

Comment: Taking your other comment literally, you just halved the capacitance when you put them in series.

Comment: yeah if you connect them in series, time would be reduced and the tube would last longer.